# scrape a file and delete lines with a certain range of numbers

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to scrape a file with content similar to this this:

```
"addressString":"12366 NY","eId":"64174f8e42b7fdfb837f68b","hasImage":false,"Price":5800,"Name":Bernard Bernoulli,"headline":"nice Fiat 500, red, slight damage to left mirror"
"addressString":"451 Citadel","eId":"sd3448e42b7368b","year":1976,"hasImage":true,"Price":12220,"Name":Edward Diego,"headline":"Mercedes SLX, no issues"
"addressString":"1321 Bejing","eId":"3102ffdb837fssdff3","Price":350,"Name":Jet Li,"headline":"Dodge Viper, no engine, no tires, no windshield; only cash"
```

I want to delete all lines with a "Price": lower than 950.

Also, the amount and position of named sections (like "Price", "year", "Name", etc.) differs from line to line.

I tried with **sed** and a regex which ranges from 0 to 950:

```
sed '/"Price":([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-4][0-9]|950),/d' <inputfile >outputfile
```

...but it did not work.

Any help is appreciated.
Using sed on Ubuntu Linux 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you did not specify flag `-E` for `sed`.

In your case `sed` uses [BRE](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-syntax.html), and parentheses here don't have special meaning unless they escaped with `\`.

You can either escape all symbols with special meaning in regex by `\` or use key `-E`.

Comment: oh crap, that was really simple. Thanks so much!! I didn't even think about having to escape some of the characters.
With `sed -E '/"Price":([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-4][0-9]|950),/d' <inputfile >outputfile` it works flawlessly!

Comment: I personally would recommend using `-E` and leaving your regex as is. This form widely recognizable and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

This almost looks like JSON data, with some small tweaks it is, i.e. you can parse the data with `jq`, e.g.:

```
<infile sed -E 's/"Name":([^,]+)/"Name":"\1"/; s/^/{ /; s/$/ }/' |
jq 'select(.Price > 950)'
```

Output:

```json
{
  "addressString": "12366 NY",
  "eId": "64174f8e42b7fdfb837f68b",
  "hasImage": false,
  "Price": 5800,
  "Name": "Bernard Bernoulli",
  "headline": "nice Fiat 500, red, slight damage to left mirror"
}
{
  "addressString": "451 Citadel",
  "eId": "sd3448e42b7368b",
  "year": 1976,
  "hasImage": true,
  "Price": 12220,
  "Name": "Edward Diego",
  "headline": "Mercedes SLX, no issues"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regexps for numeric comparisons, use numeric comparisons. e.g. using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/"Price":([^,]+)/,a) && (a[1] < 950)' file
"addressString":"1321 Bejing","eId":"3102ffdb837fssdff3","Price":350,"Name":Jet Li,"headline":"Dodge Viper, no engine, no tires, no windshield; only cash"
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/"Price":([^,]+)/) && (substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)+0 < 950)' file
"addressString":"1321 Bejing","eId":"3102ffdb837fssdff3","Price":350,"Name":Jet Li,"headline":"Dodge Viper, no engine, no tires, no windshield; only cash"
```